# Will blind people be blind in Heaven?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-matthew

[Matthew 18:9, NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2018:9&version=NIV):

> And if your eye causes you to stumble, gouge it out and throw it away. It is better for you to enter life with one eye than to have two eyes and be thrown into the fire of hell.

Does this mean that people who are (or become) blind in this life will be blind in Heaven as well?

The logical extension of this idea would be, if you're in a car accident, and your legs are lost, and you become blind... then you die from complications a day later, you'll be a blind paraplegic in Heaven. Is this a fair understanding of the verse?

Comment: I've never read "enter life" in this verse as entering heaven but as being born.  So it is better to have been born (half-)blind than to live with full sight and end up in hell.

Comment: nope. the deaf will hear as well.

Comment: @studiohack: source?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Isaiah 35:5-6a,10 NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2035:5-10&version=NIV):

> Then will the eyes of the blind be opened
>     and the ears of the deaf unstopped.
>   <sup>6</sup>Then will the lame leap like a deer,
>     and the mute tongue shout for joy.
>   *(verse 10 shows context of Zion)*
>   <sup>10</sup> and those the LORD has rescued will return.
>   They will enter Zion with singing;
>     everlasting joy will crown their heads.
>   Gladness and joy will overtake them,
>     and sorrow and sighing will flee away.

Just because you enter one way, doesn't mean you will stay that way. As the language of Isaiah is written you will be made whole. Besides Jesus wasn't stating you WOULD enter eternal life mamed, He was saying even if you were to enter heaven mamed, Wouldn't that be better than all of you being thrown in the fire of hell? Check out this link for other scriptures related to getting a new body in heaven, http://www.crossroad.to/heaven/contents/new_bodies.htm

Answer (score 1):

Also could this be somewhat of a theoretical question?
Maybe it's not saying that you would actual enter heaven blind, but more along the lines of making the point that, even if that were the case, wouldn't that be better than the alternative?